# How I can do this in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

I want to make a query that select fields using 'like' but I am not satisfied with the result, for example my register says, "wood table work 45" but if my query is SELECT * FROM schema1.table1 WHERE description LIKE "%table for work%"; returns nothing, I don't want the user need write exactly "table work" or "wood table" to have a result.

Comment: So does it mean you want the row returned in case of any word matched?

Comment: Consider using `FULL Text Search`

Comment: You probably want a full text index.  That is the place to start for this type of functionality.

Comment: yeah jakub wrona.

Answer (score 0):

Create first a FULL TEXT Index on the column you wants to query this way :

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IndxDescription` (`description`);
```

You don't need to run an indexer daemon, MySQL does the index / reindex automatically.

FYI: Full-text is supported in InnoDB / MyISAM only in MySQL
reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

If you are looking for a more robust solution, consider taking a look on ElasticSearch : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Natural Language Fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)